# How to render a node on behalf of another user (as an admin or without accessCheck)

Tags: entities

**Context** : I use the following code to replace a token by a rendered node.

The resulted text is sent by email

```
$renderable = $view_builder->view($node, 'token', $langcode);
$replacements[$original] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($renderable);
```

This is working fine except when **I am queuing the mails to be sent**

Because, in this case, the upper code runs in a queue and `NodeAccessControlHandler::checkAccess` and `NodeAccessControlHandler::checkFieldAccess` are called with an anonymous account (id=0).

This leads to an `AccessRessult::forbidden()` (because in my setup, anonymous can't see those fields and/or this node) and the rendered node is empty...

**Thus my question is**:

How to render a node (in a queue) "in behalf of" an admin user?

or

How to explain to my overrided `NodeAccessControlHandler` that we are in a queue and that it can safely give access (without security concerns)

Comment: Similar to [How do I run cron as an authenticated user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183354/how-do-i-run-cron-as-an-authenticated-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of **@No Sssweat** I could find a solution:

**Summary**: the problem appeared when emails were sent via a queue in a cron. The cron is running as an anonymous user, and, in this case, the drupal viewBuilder/Rendering system doesn't have enough permission to display some fields/nodes.

**Solution**: Adapt the `processItem` function of the QueueWorker in order to switch the current user into an admin user at the beginning of the process and switch back at the end.

I my use case, I overrode the QueueWorker provided by another module. Here is my code with the injection of the switcher service: (feel free to comment)

```
/**
 * The account switcher service.
 *
 * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountSwitcherInterface
 */
protected $accountSwitcher;

public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, SubscribersInterface $subscribers, AccountSwitcherInterface $account_switcher)
{
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $subscribers);
    $this->accountSwitcher = $account_switcher;
}

public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition)
{
    return new static($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $container->get('message_subscribe.subscribers'), $container->get('account_switcher'));
}

public function processItem($data)
{
    $this->accountSwitcher->switchTo(new UserSession([
        'uid' => 1,
        'name' => 'cron_admin',
        'roles' => ['administrator'],
    ]));
    parent::processItem($data);
    $this->accountSwitcher->switchBack();
}
```