# module to test if e-mail is working

Tags: 7, rules, emails, cron, actions

In D7 I'm trying to determine the best way to periodically check if e-mail is working. I'm looking for a way to create a workflow that, say, on cron would check the day of the month, if it's the day that has been configured in the module as the test day, send an e-mail. Check the return value on the e-mail function. If the e-mail failed, write the error to the logs and/or send it to another service, like Slack, to alert the team.

Is there a module that comes close to doing this, or can something be cobbled together with actions and rules, etc? Thanks!

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84268/use-hook-cron-to-send-daily-mail-but-i-get-45-the-same-mail-every-day/275911#275911, and use Mail Logger module

Answer (score 0):

What I did instead: Since all I really want to know is when e-mail fails, I went the watchdog rules route instead. Combining watchdog rules with the Slack API allowed me to create a rule that sends a slack message whenever one of our sites has an smtp error.