# Rule that sends one email out at specific time each day with view content in it

Tags: 7, views, rules, emails

I have 5 different views that show different metrics within blocks on the front of my website. I want a rule that can send this information to me by email each day at a certain time. How do I do this, as there are 5 views, so I need the information put into one textual email. An ideal world would actually be a screengrab or pdf of the front page of my website, but I assume this is a bit more complex. I installed the module called [Once Per Day](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_onceperday)

I started with:

```
EVENTS: Once per day

CONDITIONS: Current day of the week
Parameter: Day of the week is a: Working day (Monday to Friday)
```

But I have no idea how to set the actual time of this or how to get any of my view data into the email.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84268/use-hook-cron-to-send-daily-mail-but-i-get-45-the-same-mail-every-day/275911#275911