# testing scheduled file deletions

Tags: 7, files, configuration

Long story short, is there a correct way to override `DRUPAL_MAXIMUM_TEMP_FILE_AGE`?

I'm working on testing a fix to a module I wrote a while back that handles some uploaded files. I neglected to call `file_usage_delete` and set `file_managed` status to 0. To test my changes more quickly, I'd like to schedule files for deletion after doing some operations on them. To do this reasonably I had to reduce the turn around time on deletions to something on the order of minutes than hours. I went ahead and edited system.module where `DRUPAL_MAXIMUM_TEMP_FILE_AGE` is defined as 6 hours, but the comments immediately preceding the defines indicate:

> @file
> Configuration system that lets administrators modify the workings of the site.

I checked the places where this value is used, and it doesn't look to be actually configurable besides editing system.module directly. Maybe I'm missing something?

**Is there a correct way to set this that doesn't involve "hacking core"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't configurable. You would be better served writing your own routine that executes on a regular interval and searches for temporary files whose creation age is greater than 10 minutes ago.

The DRUPAL_MAXIMUM_TEMP_FILE_AGE constant is specifically intended to inform Drupal on when a file that has not yet been set to permanent should be removed.

If you take a look at **[system.module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/7.x)**, the relevant code is contained in a [hook_cron()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7.x) implementation. The code reads:

```
  $result = db_query('SELECT fid FROM {file_managed} WHERE status <> :permanent AND timestamp < :timestamp', array(
    ':permanent' => FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT,
    ':timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME - DRUPAL_MAXIMUM_TEMP_FILE_AGE,
  ));
```

My recommendation is to simply implement your own `hook_cron()` and use the same code, but calculate for files older than 10 minutes.

You will also need for cron to execute on a 10 minute interval. For this, you'll need to add a crontab and install either [ultimate_cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) or [elysisia_cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron). I prefer **ultimate_cron**.

Please see my answer to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/298701/67688) for more information on setting up crontab on a 60 second interval for maximum timeliness. You'll then use elysia_cron or ultimate_cron to control the actual job execution interval.

Comment: As an aside: Drupal's codebase is typically intended to serve as a demonstration of best practices and the "Drupal way," so copying the patterns established by Drupal will usually be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks Beau for taking the time to answer. Long story short, the answer is "No", which is what I figured. This was more of a curiosity for me, the code comment about system.module being a "configuration system" is misleading. I did find that usage of DRUPAL_MAXIMUM_TEMP_FILE_AGE, which lead me to believe it wasnt *actually* configurable. Outside of testing, the 6 hour deletion schedule will be adequate.