# How to get node's title and send list of it to mail

Tags: 7, rules, emails

I am about to send an email to website admin.

First of all, there will be a function to get list of node's title that city field equal to 'barcelona'.

After that, the list will be send to website admin once every day using e-mail.

Any idea on how to do this with Rules or custom module?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom module and implement [hook_cron()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7).

See:

https://drupal.org/developing/modules

Also check this post:
 [How to create a task which run at cron time and send emails to users?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10542/how-to-create-a-task-which-run-at-cron-time-and-send-emails-to-users)

```
function get_node_titles() {
    $result = db_query('SELECT n.title FROM {node} n');

    $titles = array();
    foreach($result as $item) {
        $titles[]  = $item->title;
    }

    return $titles;
}
```

Comment: but how to get all node title and put it in the email body?

Comment: I have updated my post, Call get_node_titles() function, it will returns all node titles in array format.